# JavaScript - Google Calendar API Error 400 - location "alt" - Update Recurring Event SERIES

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

**Can anyone help me update a Recurring Event SERIES without getting the error 400 for `location: alt` that I'm getting below?**

When I try to update all recurring events via the Google Calendar API series I get the following error:

> https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/_84qkagpj6oqj6b9o6gs30b9k8kr3aba28oo3cba46co42h236oq3cgpm60?alt=json400()

which contains this message:

> ```
> {"error":
>   {"errors":
>   [{
>    "domain":"global",
>    "reason":"invalidAltValue",
>    "message":"Unknown output format: json 400",
>    "locationType":"parameter",
>    "location":"alt"
>   }],
>   "code":400,
>   "message":"Unknown output format: json 400"
>   }
> }
> ```

**Call triggering error:**

```
var recurringEvent = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2017-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2017-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=2017-06-06T03:59:59.000Z'
  ]
};

var eventId = this.props.user.calendarEventRecurringEventId;  // POSSIBLY THE ISSUE: I use the Recurring Event Id here because I am trying to update all events in the series rather than the individual event.
this.updateEvent(recurringEvent, eventId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error [`invalidAltValue`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#400_Bad_Request) means that the `alt` parameter value specifies an unknown output format. And that the value for the `alt` URL parameter was not recognized.

I have tried your code and I got no error.

[image]

Comment: Where is the alt parameter being set?  I am not setting it anywhere and I don't see it in the documentation here (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events).  To recreate my issue: create a recurring event, then try to update the recurring event series (all events related to the recurring event, rather than a single instance of the recurring event) with my code.